# Image pre-processing for text recognize with tesseract or puma.net

Tags: c#, tesseract

How i can pre-processing image with OpenCVdotnet for better text recognize?
I try tesseract wrapper and Puma.NET,but my result is worse... how i can improve result?

```
            #region Tesseract
                Bitmap pictureInfoArea = src.ToBitmap();
                        TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine("tessdata/", "rus", EngineMode.Default);
                        //engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
                        var page = engine.Process(pictureInfoArea, PageSegMode.Auto);

                        string sTesseract = page.GetText();

        #endregion
        #region Puma.NET
                        PumaPage pumaInfoArea = new PumaPage(pictureInfoArea);

                        using (pumaInfoArea)
                        {
                            // Changing default settings
                            pumaInfoArea.FileFormat = PumaFileFormat.TxtAnsi;
                            pumaInfoArea.EnableSpeller = true;
                            pumaInfoArea.Language = PumaLanguage.Russian;

                            // Recognizing and saving results to a file
                            string sPuma = pumaInfoArea.RecognizeToString();

                            //MessageBox.Show(s);
                        }
    #endregion
```

Comment: put an example of your images please!

Comment: http://s14.radikal.ru/i187/1408/2c/733dd63f5334.jpg This text from document with russians chars. My result is worse,

Comment: you need to remove the background, and as your characters are not clearly separated, tesseract will be confused. SO you need also to implement an algorithm that make some small spaces between those combined letters. Is that what you need ?

Comment: Yes, it will great, but how i can do it? Do you now some algorithm`s who can do it? (separate)

Comment: to separate the characters, first of all you need to separate a line aside, then take its vertical projections, then you can estimate the negative peaks who represent the space between each two characters. Something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/WuWpG.jpg

Comment: Or another way to separate characters, is to let tesseract separate them, then compute the width of separated object, and estimate how many characters are in this object, comparing it with predefined width of original character

Comment: big thx for response, i try second way, but tesseract not always finds all characters(for example, picture from second answer)! may be set variables can help me set parametrs for better recognition!?

Comment: the projection suggestion should help for this kind of image

Comment: i try separate chars, but result worse again, may be train tesseract can help me?

Comment: please, put an example of the resulted images after separation

Comment: http://s017.radikal.ru/i421/1409/c6/036d8638e5bc.png http://s44.radikal.ru/i103/1409/d7/82f31a1627b1.png http://s017.radikal.ru/i401/1409/8e/a715c01203a4.png For example, i separate chars and then recognize with tesseract, PageSegMode.SingleChar mode, but result more bad then recognize all text in full. What i do wrong?

Comment: yes you need to retrain tesseract by a new set of your real characters

Comment: Do you know some good tutorial about tesseract train?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.cedric.ws/how-to-train-tesseract-301) is a tutorial explaining how to train your own language. I suggest that you install [jTessBoxeditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html), that help you well in training your patterns,after applying the letters separation algorithm. jTessBoxeditor has a GUI interface letting you train your own dataset

or

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) you have another tutorial to train Tesseract3 for a new language.

Have a look at this one (i did not test it) sunnypage.ge/en http://lib.psnc.pl/Content/358/PSNC_Tesseract-FineReader-report.pdf

Comment: Can i train tesseract without letters separation? Why when i separate chars(PageSegMode.SingleChar), recognize more worse, than i give tesseract all text without separation(PageSegMode.Auto)? Big Thx for help!!!

Comment: tesseract will face troubles when you provide it connected letters, so do your preprocess on image, to get a better image, then provide it to tesseract.

Comment: I should get separate pictures with letters and then give to tesseract with PageSegMode.SingleChar, or make one pictures with separates leters? i can`t do second way...

Comment: For me I collect the real separated letters in one page then I use  jTessBoxeditor to get the training samples. In general this tool replace the step of boxes creation.

Comment: Great tool! But how i can add my traineddata file to existing rus.traineddata file?

Comment: check the tutorials i sent you, it should be the last two steps.

combine_tessdata lang